# Not able to explore json.loads() code with pdb

Tags: python, json, debugging, pdb

I want to see what code is executing when I convert json string to python dictionary using json.loads()

e.g.

```
import json  
s = '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'  # input json string
d = json.loads(s)  # output dictionary object
```

I tried to see inner logic by debugging the code and reaching at core logic and parsing.

```
import json  
s = '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'  # input json string
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
d = json.loads(s)  # output dictionary object
```

By stepping into `d = json.loads(s)` I am able to reach `loads()` present in [json/**init**.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/json/__init__.py)

Which further take me into `decode()` and then `raw_decode()` method present in `JSONDecoder` class in [json/decoder.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/json/decoder.py)

```
def raw_decode(self, s, idx=0):
        """Decode a JSON document from ``s`` (a ``str`` beginning with
        a JSON document) and return a 2-tuple of the Python
        representation and the index in ``s`` where the document ended.
        This can be used to decode a JSON document from a string that may
        have extraneous data at the end.
        """
        try:
            obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
        except StopIteration as err:
            raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
        return obj, end
```

In `raw_decode()` I am not able to further step into `obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)` pdd send me to last line `return obj, end`

```
(Pdb) l
350             This can be used to decode a JSON document from a string that may
351             have extraneous data at the end.
352     
353             """
354             try:
355  ->             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
356             except StopIteration as err:
357                 raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
358             return obj, end
[EOF]
(Pdb) s
> /usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py(358)raw_decode()
-> return obj, end
(Pdb)
```

I want to see inner code and I want to reach to that code using pdb as I am expecting that by stepping into `pdb` will take to inner code.
I am not able to reach even `make_scanner = c_make_scanner or py_make_scanner` in [json/scanner.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/json/scanner.py) and `_json` module.

How can I reach to core iteration and parsing logic using debugging?

Comment: d is reserved in pdb. Use different names for your variables. Something longer than two characters.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because Python is using a native version of JSON scanner, so you can't use the Python debugger. See [json/scanner.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/json/scanner.py#L5):

```
try:
    from _json import make_scanner as c_make_scanner
except ImportError:
    c_make_scanner = None
```

If the C / native version is not available, a fallback version written in Python is used instead (also defined in the file linked above).